# Ayuda al hacer figuras con Graphics2D Java

Tags: java

necesito ayuda con mi codigo, dejo el link:

https://paste.ofcode.org/9Mt8yqPVFhFYg9HyPxz4pn

Lo que pasa es que al correrlo, no me muestra la figura completa, y necesito que la muestre, pero no se como hacerlo, lo he intentado pero no lo logro.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda o sus comentarios, gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @krozer, según las normas de la comunidad no se debe colocar codigo como imagenes, codigo externo (en un link diferente) ni codigo en los comentarios, precisamente recaes en colocar codigo externo, ademas el codigo debe ser algo llamado ejemplo minimo y verificable (el minimo codigo que se necesita para reproducir tu problema), si consideras que todo el codigo que tienes es lo minimo posible para reproducir el problema entonces intenta realizar una versión lo mas reducida posible que nos ayude a reproducir y comprender el problema para nosotros ayudarte.

Comment: De paso te recomiendo dar una vuelta por el [tour] y leer [ask], para poder mejorar tanto esta pregunta como las futuras que hagas, tambien recuerda entonces que el codigo no debe estar en un link, puedes poner tu código aquí directamente en la pregunta y formatearlo como codigo.